# .NET Core Web API - Return an Excel spreadsheet AND list of strings in same response?

Tags: c#, arrays, file, export, asp.net-core-webapi

As far as I know, in C#, Excel is sent over the wire as a binary array, along with some metadata that identifies it to the frontend/browser as an excel file:

`return File(resultStream.ToArray(), contentType);`

But is there a way I can return an excel spreadsheet AND an array of strings? The object would look something like this:

`response {
   document: [130,200,31,7,35,92...],
   strings: ["alpha", "bravo", "charlie"...]
}`

And then I suppose the frontend would have to take that document, parse it to an excel spreadsheet (?) and "give it to the browser" so it will actually download to the client's computer?

I considered having these be separate requests, but would rather keep it all in one request/response if possible.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up sending the strings with some other data required to create the spreadsheet in the front end. Ideal? Maybe not. But it works(tm)